# Are there any words (synonyms) meaning 'credit to somebody'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

So I have included some information from other books in my presentation, and I want to give credits to those people who have written them.I hope you can help me with this difficulty.By the way, do we use 'credit to somebody' in formal written English?

Comment: Are you following a style guide?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help me with this one.

Comment: In presentations, I've normally seen people use "Credit: [creator]" when they use pictures or artwork that they want to give credit for (eg. "Credit: Getty Images"). For giving credit to authors at the end of a presentation, usually presenters will have a References section with each author listed alphabetically, but you could also use footnotes and inline references if you want to be more specific. "Credit to smbd" is not normally used in formal written English, since smbd is a placeholder. You could replace "smbd" with "unknown author" perhaps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit is given when you use (with lawful permission) someone else’s work and ideas to develop your own. 
Ideas and contributions can also be ‘acknowledged’ where there is insufficient material or copyright issues to warrant being ‘credited’

If the material is a straight lift, (rather than your interpretation of their work), the protocol is to ‘Reference’ the other author/researcher by putting details of their publication in your reference sheet/page